# ctrl+r-shift and ctrl+l-shift to toggle direction

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, chromium

I want toggle between direction inside Chrome and Firefox. For example when I'm focusing on the text area and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l-shift</kbd> the text area direction go to the left (ltr) and when i hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r-shift</kbd> the direction go to the right (rtl).

My clients have this on the Windows and they don't want move to the Ubuntu until they have this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Extension for Chrome and Firefox to switch the direction:

[Switch Direction for Chrome and Chromium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switch-direction/fldkjfjmcadcklboajlnclnfjpdopcce?hl=en)

[Switch Direction for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switch-direction/)

After Installing the extension:

1. Go to the settings and turn on `Enable Switch Direction with Ctrl+Shift+X`
2. Restart the browser.

Now you can switch direction by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>